# SVN: Email notification after svn update PHP

Tags: svn, notifications

After `svn update` I recived this message:

"*You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root*"

How Can I remove this message or stop this notification ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

SVN isn't supposed to send mail. The message isn't relevant to your last command - it's just that bash checks your UNIX mailbox each time before issuing a command prompt.

UPDATE:

You can hack `bash` configuration to delete a revevant autocommand but you shouldn't - otherwize your UNIX mailbox will gradually get cluttered with mail and/or you may miss an important automated notice.

Instead, run `mail` command to see what you received and either disable the sender(s) (it's typically `logwatch`) or redirect your UNIX mail to an external e-mail address by uncommenting and editing the last line in `/etc/aliases` and running `newaliases` after that.

Comment: How Can I stop this notification ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a post-commit hook on, sounds like.

In the subversion distribution are several hook scripts which send email. Look in the directories

tools/hook-scripts and

contrib/hook-scripts

and modify them to your needs.

Comment: see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks